# Understanding Azure PaaS metrics

Tags: azure, memory, cloud, monitoring, azureportal

I have a App Service plan consisting of 2 S3 instances (each is 4 cores and 7 GB RAM). In the portal on the service plan blade I see this:

[image]

What exactly do these percentages mean? Is it 44.41% of 7 + 7 GB RAM? The plan hosts 7 web apps and I get an alert that one of the app exceeds 85% memory limit. How is that possible? 85% of what? Does that mean each app gets 7/7 = 1GB on each instance?  If I open a specific web app blade I see the following:

[image]

Is it ~1GB on each of 2 instances or total? How do I understand memory consumption by each web app per service plan instance?

Is there any good tutorial on these metrics as the official documentation is not very clear?

Comment: I have scoured the web looking for these answers over the past year. I'm unaware of any authoritative article that answers any of these questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first graph,The **memory percentage** showing is indeed the memory used by the resources in the app service plan . So its actually 44.41% of 7+7 Gb . If the resources are using 85% of it then it will by default create a alert to user . So in that case ,upgrade the instances to allocate more memory and cores or scaling up the instances so that the performance of the app is increased and user won't receive the alert.

The other one is **DataIn** is the average incoming bandwidth used across all instances of the plan and for the **Memory Working Set** is referred as the  maximum physical memory of the RAM used for a process performed by instances  .

Please refer more to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-monitor) for monitoring app service.